# Split two variables with the same string in starting of the variable name

Tags: php, split

I have the following :

```
$variable = bl45789;
```

The value `bl` will be always included in my variable.

How can I get only 45789.

With explode maybe ?

Comment: If it's always two characters, use `substr($variable, 2)`

Comment: @knittl there is no `substring` method - just `substr`.

Comment: substr() is better, you can also use $arr = explode('bl',$variable);$number = $arr[1];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`substr`](http://php.net/substr)

```
$variable = 'bl45789';
$output   =  substr($variable, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$var = 'bl45789';
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $var, $result);
echo $result; // will display 45789
```